# Add border and background color when I click the yes button

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am developing a kind of text boxes for comments.
When I click on the YES button I would like the box where the click came from, to have some kind of borders and a background color in order to signal that the click came from that box.

Can someone help me?

[BLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3rqch2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**code**

```
<div class="Submitcomments" *ngFor="let c of data; let  i = index;">
    <div>
        <div class="row rowComments" style="margin-top: 11px;">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea  #myinput type="text" class="form-control AreaText" rows="2"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: -20px; margin-left: 5px;">
            <button *ngIf="c.currentState=='pause'" class="btn reply" (click)="adjustState(i)">Yes</button>
            <button *ngIf="c.currentState=='start'" class="btn reply1" (click)="adjustState(i)">No</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the `[ngStyle]` binding in your html.

Something like this:

```
<textarea #myinput type="text" class="form-control AreaText" rows="2"
  [ngStyle]="{
    'background-color': c.currentState=='start' ? '#daf4d5' : 'initial', 
    'border': c.currentState=='start' ? '1px solid green' : ''
  }">
</textarea>
```

There are shorter ways to write the [`ngStyle`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) but this one allows you to choose a style for box elements that aren't clicked too. 
Also, you might want to move the `ngStyle` value in your component as a string, and use that instead (to make the html more readable).

Answer (score 1):

You can use use `AfterViewInit` to wait until the component has loaded. Then just update each `textarea` styles everytime the child `btn` is clicked inside of each element `.Submitcomments`.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';   

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let submitComments = document.querySelectorAll('.Submitcomments');
    [].slice.call(submitComments).forEach((submitComment, index) => {
        submitComment.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            submitComment.querySelector('textarea').style.border = '1px solid red';
        });
    });
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qe9hac?file=src/app/app.component.ts

**NOTE**: I'm not an angular 2 developer, so I'm sure there is a more "angular" type of way to do this. But this works for now.

Comment: I would not recommend using `querySelector` unless really needed. Angular provides a lot of ways to handle DOM elements and querySelector should be closer to a last resort imo.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help ! When we click on the button, it changes from YES to No and the borders change color. It's great, but is there a way to return the YES state to the edges disappear, that is, I want to return to the initial state?

Comment: @Jojofoulk 
One of the ways I thought about using was with JQuery, but I have seen that it is not the best solution. Hence I have no idea how I will apply this correctly :(

Comment: @Jojofoulk Like I said, im sure there is a more angular way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

try this also don't forget to upvote me if this is what you need becuse this takes time for me to do and i dont have time wasting to do this alot but if this isnt working at all you dont have to upvote me im just saying if it works remember to upvote me

```js
window.onload = function() {
//onclick event

    document.getElementById("yes").onclick = function fun() {
 

       var element = document.getElementById("yes");
  element.classList.add("yeep");
            element.classList.remove("unk");


    }
}
```

```css
.yeep{
background-color:green ;
border-color:limegreen ;
border-width:5px;
color:white;
}
.unk{

background-color:darkgray;
border-color:gray;
border-width:5px;
color:white;
}
```

```html
<button class='unk' id = 'yes'>yes!</button>
```